# Finding $a, b, c$ values of a polynomial from a graph.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I was doing my homework and I am now stuck on question number 7 which is:

The diagram shows the curve with the equation $y = (x + a)(x - b)^2$ where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers.

(i) Write down the values of $a$ and $b$, and also of $c$, given that the curve crosses the $y$-axis at $(0, c)$.

I have attached a picture of my text book here:

[image]

I have so far found $b$ like this:

$(x - b)^2 = x^2 - 2bx + b^2$

Since $y = 0$ at $x = 1$,

$0 = 1 - 2b + b^2$

Solving that quadratic equation gives us  $b = 1$.

I need to find $a$ and $c$ and I am totally puzzled on how to find them.

Comment: For $a$ the solution is the same... only you have a first order equation. Then, to solve for $c$, put $x=0$ in the original equation.

Comment: @N74 My textbook says a and c are `2`

Comment: You are told the equation is $(x+a)(x-b)^2$ with $a,b$ positive integers. Looking at the graph, the positive root must be at 1, so $b=1$. The negative root must be at $-2$, so $a=2$. Then the equation has constant term $ab^2=2$, so $c=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the graph it is evident that the roots are $-2$ and $1$ ($1$ being a repeated root),

So the equation becomes: 
$$(x+2)(x-1)^2=0$$
Comparing it with $$(x+a)(x-b)^2=0$$ We find $a=2,b=1$

Also for finding the point $(0,c)$ we can plug in $x=0$ in the equation $y=(x+2)(x-1)^2$ and we get $c=2$

Comment: Woah. Is it possible to find if for exanple we did not know it cuts - 2

Comment: @HassanAlthaf I don't get what you mean?

Comment: we know the curve cuts the x axis at -2, can we still find $a$ without that information?

Comment: No, if you don't use another point of intersection, you cannot determine $a$,

Comment: I meant that if it still did intersect but we did not know that the x coordinate was '-2'

Comment: That's precisely what I'm saying, In order to get a unique value of $a$, you require a point of intersection, if instead of $-2$, it would have intersected $x$ axis at $-3$, then we would have had $a=3$

Comment: Oh thank you very much